# air.Microphone.getMicrophone();

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs3

may i know how to use this getMicrophone with simpleFLVWriter to create flv with sound? can elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the raw waveform of sound data coming from the Microphone. Sorry! You'd have to use some server-side code to get the microphone data and send it back to your application.

Answer (score 1):

http://theflashblog.com/?p=1426

the new raw microphone access feature coming in AIR 2.0